# "I was given this number by (someone) to arrange ... " - Is this phrase correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

> I **was given** this number by (someone) to arrange ...

Is this a correct (part of a) sentence in the context of contacting someone regarding a job interview? It seems a bit awkward to me but I also feel like it is grammatically correct. I couldn't find anything about this structure: was given ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that Passive is often used to make the context in which a sentence is written more formal and appealing to the subtle eye. I think it is the case here, too.

The sentence is grammatically correct, though there are two alternatives to put **give** in Passive.

> My grandmother gave me an apple. (direct object + indirect object)

In Passive:

> I was given an apple.
>
> An apple was given **to** me.

As far as **by** is concerned in your sentence, it can or could be omitted for there is no need to mention the agent because Passive is used when s/he is unknown or unimportant.

If you are looking for a way to rephrase your sentence, here's what I would say:

> A colleague/friend/relative of mine gave this number to me.
>
> I came across this number by word of mouth.
>
> This number was recommended to me.